# Issue with singleton scope bean in case

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, singleton

I have a spring boot project in which I have implemented chain of responsibility pattern. I have created chains of multiple service class.
Each service is of scope Singleton. Now I have 2 threads are accessing the bean which is singleton, then in this case modifications done by one thread is affecting the other thread working on the same bean. I tried making the bean scope as request but it didn't work.

**TransactionChainContext - defining chains**

```
@Service 
public class TransactionChainContext {

@Autowired
TransactionChain validationChainOne;

@Autowired
TransactionChain validationChainTwo;

@Autowired
TransactionChain validationChainThree;

@Autowired
TransactionChain validationChainFour;

@Autowired
TransactionChain validationChainFive;

/* Execute by Thread 1 */
 public void saveTransactionInChain(List<Transaction> txnList) {                      
    validationChainOne.nextChain(validationChainTwo);
    validationChainTwo.nextChain(validationChainThree);
    validationChainThree.nextChain(validationChainFour);
    validationChainFour.nextChain(null);

    validationChainOne.processChain(txnList);
}

/* Execute by Thread 2 but it changes the chaing for thread 1 as well */

 public void saveChainTwo(List<Transaction> txnList) {                    
    validationChainOne.nextChain(validationChainFour);
    validationChainFour.nextChain(validationChainFive);
    validationChainFive.nextChain(null);

   validationChainOne.processChain(txnList);
}
```

}

**TransactionChain interface**

```
public interface TransactionChain {

void nextChain(TransactionChain transactionChain);

void processChain(List<Transaction> txnList);
```

}

**EDIT : Validation class**

```
@Service
public class ValidationChainOne implements TransactionChain {


TransactionChain nextTransactionChain;



@Override
public void nextChain(TransactionChain transactionChain) {
    this.nextTransactionChain = transactionChain;
}

@Override
public void processChain(List<Transaction> txnList)  {
    // some business logic
     //filtering txns bases on validations
     if(nextTransactionChain !=null){
        nextTransactionChain.processChain(txnList); // passing filtered txnList
     }
}
```

}

**What I tried**

In order to make sure that both threads does not affect each other , I made bean scope as request

```
@Scope(value = "request",  proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

but got following error

```
'scopedTarget.ValidationChainOne': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:368)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
```

Comment: Consider synchronizing the singleton methods so that only one thread has access to a shared resource.

Comment: @tomerpacific synchronizing will affect the performance very badly .

Comment: What you should do is make your chain prototype scoped and create `@Bean` methods that configure the different chains you want and inject those into the service, instead of combining the chains in the service. Basically you should move the construction of the chain out of your service.

Comment: @M.Deinum isn't making the bean as prototype,  will have extra memory utilisation ? as it will create object on each request

Comment: No it won't create an object on each request (prototype != request scope), it will only create objects for each injection point.

Comment: @M.Deinum Would you mind providing an example of how you propose to create `@Bean`. As far as I know bean returns an object. How chains will be mapped there ? and how I will use that in my service

Comment: You are now configuring the chains in your service method, that logic has to move to `@Bean` methods. You can then inject the resulting chain into the service, with that even not knowing you are using this as a chain of responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd remove the `nextChain(...)` method from `TransactionChain` so it is immutable and therefore thread-safe. Then you could do something like

```
public class ChainProcessor {
   private TransactionChain[] steps;
   public ChainProcessor(TransactionChain... steps) { 
      this.steps = steps;
   }
   public void process(ChainContext context) { 
      Arrays.stream(steps).forEach(step -> step.processChain(context));
   }
}
```

```
/**
 * This context class only required if you need to pass state from one step to another
 */
public class ChainContext {
   public void setValue(String name, Object value) { ... }
   public <T> T getValue(String name, Class<T> type) { ... }
}
```

```
public interface TransactionChain {
   void processChain(ChainContext context);
}
```

```
@Service 
public class TransactionChainContext {

   @Autowired
   TransactionChain validationChainOne;

   @Autowired
   TransactionChain validationChainTwo;

   @Autowired
   TransactionChain validationChainThree;
   
   private ChainProcessor cp1;
   private ChainProcessor cp2;

   @PostConstruct
   public void postConstruct() {
      cp1 = new ChainProcessor(validationChainOne, validationChainTwo, validationChainThree);
      cp2 = new ChainProcessor(validationChainThree, validationChainTwo, validationChainOne);
   }

   public void saveChainOne() { 
      cp1.process(new ChainContext());
   }

   public void saveChainTwo() {                     
      cp2.process(new ChainContext());
   }
}
```

I personally hate `@Autowired` and `@PostConstruct` and never use them. I prefer final member variables and constructor injection. See [this blog post](https://odrotbohm.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) on why field injection is evil

**Edit**

In answer to Muddassir Rahman question regarding filtering a list you could do

```java
@Service 
public class TransactionChainContext {
   ...
   public void saveChainOne(List<Transaction> transactions) { 
      ChainContext context = new new ChainContext();
      context.setValue("transactions", transactions);
      cp1.process(context);
      List<Transaction> filteredTransactions = context.getValue("transactions", List.class);
      doStuff(filteredTransactions);
   }
   ...
}
```

And

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public TransactionChain validationChainOne() {
      return context -> {
         List<Transaction> transactions = context.getValue("transactions", List.class);
         List<Transaction> filteredTransactions = transactions.stream().filter(t -> !t.getName().contains("foo")).collect(Collectors.toList());
         context.setValue("transactions", filteredTransactions);
      };
   }

   @Bean
   public TransactionChain validationChainTwo() {
      return context -> {
         List<Transaction> transactions = context.getValue("transactions", List.class);
         List<Transaction> filteredTransactions = transactions.stream().filter(t -> !t.getName().contains("bar")).collect(Collectors.toList());
         context.setValue("transactions", filteredTransactions);
      };
   }
}
```

If you want to be less generic, you could have a customised context class. Eg

```java
public class ChainContext {
   private final List<Transaction> transactions;
   private final List<Predicate<Transaction>> filters = new ArrayList<>();

   public ChainContext(List<Transaction> transactions) {
      this.transactions = transactions;
   }

   public void addFilter(Predicate<Transaction> filter) {
      filters.add(filter);
   }

   public List<Transaction> getFilteredTransactions() {
      return transactions.stream()
         .filter(t -> filters.stream().allMatch(filter -> filter.test(t))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need autowired, you can move all that to a configuration class, or even use constructor injection.

Comment: As I said "I personally hate @ Autowired and @ AfterPropertiesSet and never use them. I prefer final member variables and constructor injection"

Comment: Also there is no `@AfterPropertiesSet` there is `@PostConstruct`, but if you would write a constructor you wouldn't need it either.

Comment: Ah, I'm getting confused with the [InitializingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) interface which has an `afterPropertiesSet()` method

Comment: @lance-java Please do check my edits. I am filtering my list in each chain. How I will retrieve the filtered list .